# Is there similar mechanism to Qt layouts in Borland c++?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I need to develop an app in Borland c++ 5.0 with lots of dynamically created TLabel objects fitting into dynamically created TGroupBoxes. It would be trivial with Qt layouts but I can't find anything similar in Borland.

Comment: Borland C++ is a C++ compiler. QT is a (semi-) C++ framework. Just use QT with Borland C++.

Comment: @H.Guijt Do you think BorlandC++ can build Qt?